# How to pass variable to onActivityResult() from populateViewHolder?

Tags: android, onactivityresult, getstring

I have a Firebase Recycler View which contains a button like this

```
final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();

viewHolder.btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {


                                Intent data = new Intent();

                                data.putExtra("post_key",post_key);
                                Log.d("post_key", data.getExtras().getString("post_key"));

                                data.setType("image/*");
                                data.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                startActivityForResult(data, GALLERY_REQUEST);


                            }
                        });
```

This will trigger an action in OnActivityResult(). I was trying to access the variable "post_key" in OnActivityResult. Therefore, I put it to the extra, and call the getString function in OnActivityResult.

```
final String post_key=data.getExtras().getString("post_key");
```

However, the app crashed and keeps telling me that I attempt to invoke virtual method 'getString' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the request code and the result code as well:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // here you can access the intent
            String msg = (data != null) ? data.getStringExtra("post_key") : "";
            Log.d("post_key", "Got post_key: " + msg);
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not send your data to another app - if it does not accept. The thing you are doing is not mentioned anywhere.

#### Correct Way

in `onClick` don't pass extra, and hold your `post_key` in your activity/ adapter.

```
adapter.setPostKey(post_key);
```

Then in `onActivityResult()` get this `post_key`.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String post_key = adapter.getPostKey();
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```